# What’s a calculus textbook suitable for an 11th grader?

Tags: book-recommendation

I would like to prepare for the calculus education I’m going to receive in my last year of high school, but I am lost in the amount of choices.

What is an entry-level calculus textbook that could be used by an 11th grader to gain some insight on the topic?

Comment: I would just use free online sources. I have taught calc many times and have mostly used OpenStax. For self-teaching, you can't go wrong with Khan Academy. 3b1b on youtube also has some very insightful and next-level videos, but I don't know if he has a comprehensive calc intro yet or not.

Comment: Hi kennedy. Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. There are indeed a huge number of calculus textbooks, but with more information, we can narrow down the search for you. To begin with, do you mind disclosing what country you are going to be taking the calculus course in? This will help users find a book aimed at the right level. Also, do you know type of course you will be taking? Will it be mainly focused on computation (e.g. calculating derivatives and integrals), or theory (more in the style of proof-based courses such as real analysis)?

Comment: Some possibilities, ranging from very informal overviews (e.g. Silvanus P. Thompson's book or Sawyer's book) to fairly thorough but richly expository (e.g. Morris Kline's book or the **Calculus in Context** text), see [this answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/13905/745). Assuming you're in the U.S. and "calculus" for your last HS year is AP calculus, I'd mostly recommend Sawyer (for an expository overview), and if you can find a copy, Ferrar's book for some basic early algebraic/calculus manipulative work as "warm-up" to your upcoming calculus course.

Comment: Thank you to pancini for recommending OpenStax, I will delve further into that.

Comment: Hello Joe, I’m hungarian and will be taking the course here. I don’t know whether it will have a specific topic or style, but I’m guessing that it’ll only lay the groundwork for college-level calculus.

Comment: Thank you Dave, although I don’t study in the US, I will take a look at your recommendations regardless!